# Cant get a local file opened with cURL

Tags: php, curl

Hi,

I am using this code:

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, SITE_PATH . '../../blog/index.php');
$xml_file = curl_exec($curl_handle);
preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/i", $xml_file, $matches);
$title= $matches[1];
curl_close($curl_handle);
$title= $matches[1];
```

This code is supposed to open one local file and search for the title tag to have it as a variable value. But despite no error is displayed I am getting nothing as $title.
What could be wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you have to prepend the path with an @. The @ character informs curl it is a local path. I know its weird. https://coderwall.com/p/fck2ta/how-to-send-files-via-curl-in-php

Comment: still wont work. The problem is I dont know why because there is no error or whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use existing file handlers for this, such as `file_get_contents()` or `fopen()`. cURL is for external HTTP requests, not internal directory requests.

```
$xml_file = file_get_contents(SITE_PATH . '../../blog/index.php');
preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/i", $xml_file, $matches);
$title= $matches[1];
```

Although your path doesn't seem correct. More than likely it's either `../../blog/index.php`, or`, SITE_PATH .'/blog/index.php'`

Comment: file_get_contents wont work for me for some reason. Some server restriction that I cant override myself.

Comment: Does the `SITE_PATH` variable contain an HTTP URL? if so, remove that.

Comment: Sorry, Cain, I can't see what the value of the SITE_PATH is, but I should have realized that. Can you do a `var_dump(ini_get('disable_functions'));` and see what you get back? I have a feeling these functions are disabled for some reason.

Comment: Sorry, I though that by SITE_PATH you meant the '../../blog/index.php' part. Do I have to define it somewhere else?

Comment: @Cain No. It can't, but if it contains a URL, such as `http://example.com`, or something to that effect, this will not work. The reason being that most hosting providers will disable this function, and I *believe* MAMP and WAMP come with `allow_url_fopen` disabled. And your cURL isn't working, so it all seems likely.

Comment: If the file that you'er trying to grab the contents of is up 2 directory, into the blog directory, and called index.php, then yes. If the functions I described in my previous comment are disabled all together, then no.

Comment: How can I make sure cURL is not disabled?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82774/discussion-between-ohgodwhy-and-cain-nuke).

Comment: I waited for you at the chat but I didnt see you there.